# Using redux-form fieldInputPropTypes throwing error in console

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-proptypes

I am using redux-form in my project and want to use fieldInputPropTypes, which can be imported from redux-form. I am using it like this

```
import { fieldInputPropTypes } from 'redux-form';
...
SuperComponent.propTypes = {
  ...
  input: fieldInputPropTypes.isRequired,
  ...
};
```

But then I get error in console:
``` Warning: Failed prop type: SuperComponent: prop type ``input`` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from React.PropTypes. ```

Am I using it somehow wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap it inside of `PropTypes.shape()` from 'prop-types' package.

Look at the source [here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/b2cef7191ced63fbe16841fdf84625622cac5d17/src/propTypes.js#L85).

Working example:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { fieldInputPropTypes } from 'redux-form';
...
SuperComponent.propTypes = {
  ...
  input: PropTypes.shape(fieldInputPropTypes).isRequired,
  ...
};
```

Comment: I was used to use those exported propTypes as a whole propType. I had to overlook that in the source code. Wrapping it into PropType.shape() actually worked. Thank you.